# Extract delimiter from string composed of two whole numbers

Tags: bash

I have a bash string that uses a delimiter to separate two whole numbers

```
var="23,54"
```

I want to capture the delimiter (a comma , in this case) and store it in the variable `delim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
$ var="23,54"
```

then

```
$ echo "${var//[0-9]}"
,
```

To assign the result to a variable you can use

```
delim=${var//[0-9]}
```

If you want to *validate* the format as well as extract the delimiter, I'd suggest a *regular expression* test:

```
[[ $var =~ [0-9]+([^0-9])[0-9]+ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

ex.

```
$ var=23,45; [[ $var =~ [0-9]+([^0-9])[0-9]+ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
,
```

Comment: How can I specifically determine whether there are any characters between two numbers?  For instance, determine that I have `NUM{DELIM}NUM` instead of just `NUM`.

Comment: @Red I'd suggest a regex test in that case - see edit